# Sorteio com diferentes porcentagens

Tags: php, matemática

Possuo um sistema de "abrir caixas", que funciona da seguinte forma:

A caixa pode ter X itens (quantidade que quiser) onde cada item vai ter Y% de ser ganho, sendo: # ou #.1% (não possui mais casas decimais)

Ou seja: a "Caixa um" pode ter 10 itens, onde:

1. 0.5% de chanca de ser ganho
2. 1% de chanca de ser ganho
3. 4% de chanca de ser ganho
4. 4.5% de chanca de ser ganho
5. 5% de chanca de ser ganho
6. 15% de chanca de ser ganho
7. 15% de chanca de ser ganho
8. 15% de chanca de ser ganho
9. 20% de chanca de ser ganho
10. 20% de chanca de ser ganho

Sempre a soma de porcentagem de vitoria dos itens serão de 100% redondo

Atualmente, eu só possuo uma função simples que pega um item qualquer do array dos itens na caixa:

```
$vencedor = $items[array_rand($items)];
```

E ele me trás o item "sorteado", o que preciso é que a porcentagem de cada item seja levada em conta, e não estou conseguindo isso

Tentei algumas coisas, nenhuma chegou no resultado desejado

Comment: Um jeito bem simples de fazer funcionar com o código que você já tem é popular a "caixa" conforme as porcentagens. Por exemplo, se 20% dos itens da sua caixa forem cópias do valor `10`, um sorteio de índice com `array_rand` vai bater com o item `10` aproximadamente 20% das vezes.

Comment: @bfavaretto não entendi muito bem, seria atribuir números conforme a porcentagem do item?

Comment: Seria repetir o item dentro do array de modo que ele tenha uma chance mais alta de ser sorteado.

Comment: Everton, você conseguiu testar meu código? Tem algum comentário a fazer? Abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução proposta pelo @bfavaretto nos comentários funciona perfeitamente. Aqui vai uma outra sugestão caso não tenha conseguido resolver.

Fiz uma solução baseado em um range de números que cada elemento pode ter. Quanto maior a porcentagem de chance, maior é o range de números de cada elemento. Baseado no seu exemplo, eu criei o seguinte array:

```
$items = array(

    "Item 1" => 0.5, // porcentagens
    "Item 2" => 1,
    "Item 3" => 4,
    "Item 4" => 4.5,
    "Item 5" => 5,
    "Item 6" => 15,
    "Item 7" => 15,
    "Item 8" => 15,
    "Item 9" => 20,
    "Item 10" => 20

);
```

Com isso, é gerado um novo array com o nome de cada elemento e seus respectivos ranges através deste código:

```
$valor = 1000; // valor do peso máximo e total dos itens
$inicio = 1;
$ultimo_valor = 0;

$array_elementos = array(); // array para sorteio

// cria o array para sorteio
foreach($items as $nome => $porcentagem){

    $val =  ($valor * $porcentagem) / 100;
    $valorFinal = $val + $inicio - 1;
    $array_elementos[$nome] = $inicio."-".$valorFinal;
    $inicio = $valorFinal + 1;

}
```

Veja como ficou o array `$array_elementos`:

```
Array ( 

    [Item 1] => 1-5 
    [Item 2] => 6-15 
    [Item 3] => 16-55 
    [Item 4] => 56-100 
    [Item 5] => 101-150 
    [Item 6] => 151-300 
    [Item 7] => 301-450 
    [Item 8] => 451-600 
    [Item 9] => 601-800 
    [Item 10] => 801-1000 

)
```

Agora basta sortear um número aleatório e procurar no array em qual elemento está o número. Assim:

```
// numero randômico "sorteio"
// de 1 até o valor máximo
$num_rand = rand(1, $valor);

$elemento_sorteado = "";

// procura o elemento sorteado
foreach($array_elementos as $nome => $peso){
    $valores = explode("-", $peso);
    if($num_rand >= $valores[0] && $num_rand <= $valores[1]){
        $elemento_sorteado = $nome;
        break;
    }
}

echo $elemento_sorteado;
```

Veja o código funcionando no **[ideone](https://ideone.com/NUfuqY)**

Comment: Olá, desculpe a demora p responder, acabei me enrolando no serviço e deixei isso um pouco de lado. Testei o seu código, funcionou do jeito que eu queria, obrigado!

Comment: @EvertonNeri que bom que deu certo! =) Eu ia ver se melhorava a explicação.. Talvez estivesse confusa. Mas tranquilo então. Abraço!